# IE file save/saveas/cancel dialog, is there any way to find out they selected Cancel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

This is C#, asp.net. My page does a response write to a file for downloading. I need to know if the user actually selected open or save because we raise an event to the effect that the person has downloaded the file, whether they did an open or save. But we don't want to raise that event if they hit cancel. Is something like this possible?

Comment: does the request for the file actually get sent? if not thats your clue...

Comment: How would I be able to tell that? We're getting that standard browser popup with the "Do you want to save xxx"?.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. After download the client is in control of the file.

Comment: we would have to know more about your workflow

Comment: Okay. The launch page is a grid with document hyperlinks. You click on a link, it brings up this download page as a popup window. The download page does a response.write on the name of the file it was given. Once the response.write is done, the download page goes away and you have the "Do you want to open or save file xxx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't tell if they pressed Cancel or anything else. That's not an interaction with your web page. Your web page has done its part, providing the response to the user. Now the user is interacting with the browser, telling the browser whether or not they want to accept the download.

To make a comparison: Knowing whether or not they download the file would be similar to knowing what they name the file or what folder they save it in. All of those are behaviors between the user and the browser, not between the user and your application running in the browser.

Comment: That's kinda what I thought, but I was hoping someone would have an idea that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: I think it can be done using JS, but you won't be able to do it from anything server-side.